# How to print everything after a match?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

How can I print everything after a match?

I've tried the following and it simple prints the variable "$source":

```
awk "IGNORECASE = 1;f;/some_word<\/div>/{f=1}" <<< "$source"
```

for example, source contains:

```
<code>
<code>
MATCH
<code>
<code>
<code>
```

I'd like to get:

```
<code>
<code>
<code>
```

Comment: Give the detail of $source, and do you need print the match line or not?

Comment: $source is an html code. I don't need the match line.

Comment: Do you want everything on the line AFTER the match or everything including the match or everything in the file after the match or everything in the file after the line containing the match or something else? Post some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. Remember that awk scripts have the following syntax:

```
<condition> { <action> }
```

with a default condition of true and a default action of printing the current record. When you wrote:

```
IGNORECASE = 1;f;/some_word<\/div>/{f=1}
```

that is the same as:

```
IGNORECASE = 1
f
/some_word<\/div>/ { f=1 }
```

which when you add in the default actions is the same as:

```
IGNORECASE = 1 { print $0 }
f { print $0 }
/some_word<\/div>/ { f=1 }
```

Notice that you had put the IGNORECASE=1 statement in a condition section instead of an action section so it'd always evaluate to true and so would always print the current line.

What you REALLY wanted was to set IGNORECASE at the start of the script:

```
BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 }
f { print $0 }
/some_word<\/div>/ { f=1 }
```

which can be reduced to this in your original one-line syntax:

```
BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1} f; /some_word<\/div>/ {f=1}
```

and the whole script is (use single quotes, not double to avoid shell quoting/escaping hell):

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1} f; /some_word<\/div>/ {f=1}' <<< "$source"
```

but note that IGNORECASE is GNU-awk specific, to be portable across all awks you'd do:

```
awk 'f; tolower($0) ~ /some_word<\/div>/ {f=1}' <<< "$source"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix.

```
awk "BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}f;/some_word<\/div>/{f=1}" <<< "$source"
```

Comment: I need awk to ignore case-sensitive in matching

Answer (score 0):

(although you mention awk in the question, i recently had to figure out a way to do this, so here is ) the perl alternative:

```
cat file.txt | perl -n -i -e '$should_print = 1 if /MATCH/; print $_ if $should_print'
```

Comment: `$print = 1 if /MATCH/; print $_ if $print`. Good grief. People who know perl have told me it's possible to write clear, legible scripts in perl - why on earth doesn't anyone do it then???

Comment: the line above translates to something like this: line 0: `if (/MATCH/) { $print = 1;}` and line 1 `if ($print) { print $_;)`. It can be a bit tricky at first, but you get used to it after a while.

Comment: So you named a variable `print`, like the command name? That certainly didn't help the clarity! I thought you were printing something (`$print`) then testing /MATCH/ (`1 if /MATCH/`) and doing nothing then printing again then a test (`$_ if`) for something then another print.... Can't perl scripts be written as simply `if (condition) do something` statements like you'd see in C or other common languages and in your comment pseudo-code?

Comment: apologies, im used to perl so i didn't realize that i was using the same name. That one line `if` is a perl syntax which is quite useful when you are writing oneliners like the one above.

Comment: So in perl you need to put the condition after the action and you can't just write the clear, obvious `if (/MATCH/){$should_print = 1}; if ($should_print) {print $_}` like you would in C or any Algol-based language? OK. By the way, it's a bad idea to name variables that represent conditions based on what you want to do if that condition is true as it tightly control-couples your code. Just name the variable based on what the condition IS (e.g. `found_match`) and then use that condition to do whatever you want wherever you want, print or otherwise. Thanks for the explanation.